# how to set a screen title in Install4j

Tags: install4j

I am trying to set the title and subtitle of a screen using Java code but cannot find an appropriate api.

Is there a way of setting a screen title and subtitle using Java code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the title and subtitle to installer variable expressions, like

```
${installer:myTitle}
```

Then, before the screen is activated, set the variable to the desired message:

```
context.setVariable("myTitle", "My title");
```